# Adding users and roles using WSO2 api

Tags: wso2

I was following the samples of WSO2 Greg 4.6.0 to add users and roles from two excel files(users.xls and roles.xls).
Both were created succesfully, but roles were created without any permissions !!

My roles.xls file is looking like:

ROLE1   |   login,configure

Does any body tried this sample?? Can somebody give an example to know how should i write roles?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

Permission must be like 'permission/admin/manage/resources/govern/service/add' and not like in the documents i followed (http://docs.wso2.org/download/attachments/26843195/image2013-9-10+14%3A22%3A4.png?version=1&modificationDate=1378803125000)

Regards